# How to format assembly comments 

Tags: linux, perl, awk, code-formatting

I have the following sample commented GAS code

```
cmpb $45, (%ebx)  # 45 - ASCII '-'
jne r_filename
cmpb $118, 1(%ebx) # 118 - ASCII 'v'
jne r_filename
movl    $4,%eax        # write(
movl    $1,%ebx        #   STDOUT,
movl    $Leng, %edx     #   len *
movl    $Inform, %ecx #   *Buffer
int     $0x80          # );
```

How to format comments like this using AWK:

```
cmpb $45, (%ebx)        # 45 - ASCII '-'
jne r_filename
cmpb $118, 1(%ebx)      # 118 - ASCII 'v'
jne r_filename
movl    $4,%eax         # write(
movl    $1,%ebx         #   STDOUT,
movl    $Leng, %edx     #   len *
movl    $Inform, %ecx   #   *Buffer
int     $0x80           # );
```

Comment: `M-x align-regexp` in Emacs will do this. `indent-tabs-mode` should probably be `nil` for the sake of sanity though.

Comment: Don't overlook the little languages - like GNU sed for example `sed -r '/#/!b;s/^([^#]*)(#.*)/printf "%- 40s %s" "\1" "\2"/e'` does the job too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is an answer in Perl acceptable, too?

*script.pl*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while(<>) {
        if(m/^(.+?)\s*(#.*)?$/) {
                my ($code, $comment) = ($1, $2);

                if($comment) {
                        printf "%- 40s %s\n", $code, $comment;
                }
                else {
                        print "$code\n";
                }
        }
        else {
                print;
        }
}
```

call it:

```
cat file.asm | perl script.pl
```

Comment: That fails if there is a blank line.

Comment: @TLP, [The code posted by halo] fails if there is a blank line.

Comment: @ikegami That is true. `while (<>) { m/...` would be the more correct version.

Comment: @TLP, Would have to be `if (m/...` since an unsuccessful match doesn't clear `$1` and the like.

Comment: @halo, You can remove the inner `if` if you change `/^(.+?)\s*(#.*)?$/` to `/^(.+?)\s*(#.*)$/`.

Answer (score 2):

Auto-split perl one-liner. "If it's not broken up, don't fix it."

```
perl -F/(#)/ -ape 'if (@F > 1) { $F[0] = sprintf "%-40s",$F[0]; $_ = "@F" }' file
```

Comment: It's cleaner to split using a lookahead IMO. The 'i' flag would also be useful here.

Comment: @Zaid You could do in-place edit if you wished, however shell redirection would be safer for perl beginners. Why is it cleaner to split on a lookahead? This does the same thing.

Comment: For this problem it doesn't matter, but `split /(#)/` spits out three strings `( $code, '#', $comment )` while `split /(?=#)/` returns the two `( $code, $comment )`

Comment: @Zaid I see your point. However, as you say, here it does not matter, as it is only the first string we are interested in manipulating. One might argue that it does add another space, though, when concatenating.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe'
    $_ = sprintf("%-23s %s", $1, $2)
       if /^([^#]+)(#.*)/;
' file.in > file.out
```

I left comments in the first column in the first column. Use `/^([^#]*)(#.*)/` to indent all comments.

You can also edit the file in place instead of creating a new file.

With backup:

```
perl -i~ -pe'...' file
```

Without backup:

```
perl -i -pe'...' file
```

Comment: +1 One thing that I am concerned about all our solutions is the possibility of hash signs inside quoted strings. But perhaps that does not apply to assembler code.

Comment: @TLP, Yeah, I'm aware of that. It's probably just do a `diff` and adjust/remote any improper fixes afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

C'mon guys, he specified Awk:

```
 awk -F# '{printf "%-30.30s #%s\n", $1, $2}' $oldFile > $newFile
```

The `-F#` uses the pound sign as a separator. The `printf` formats it. `%30.30s` says to print this field left justified 30 characters wide. The `%s` just says print the second field. The results are:

```
cmpb $45, (%ebx)               # 45 - ASCII '-'
jne r_filename                 #
cmpb $118, 1(%ebx)             # 118 - ASCII 'v'
jne r_filename                 #
movl    $4,%eax                # write(
movl    $1,%ebx                #   STDOUT,
movl    $Leng, %edx            #   len *
movl    $Inform, %ecx          #   *Buffer
int     $0x80                  # );
```

Comment: That outputs `#` where there weren't any before. And it doesn't handle lines with multiple `#`. (@TLP, I preferred a working solution, which is why I used `if /^([^#]+)(#.*)/` over "pretty" `-F`.) By the way, while the OP originally asked for an awk solution, he has since removed awk from the subject and added the Perl tag.

Comment: @ikegami Actually, I removed the `awk` from the title. Perhaps I shouldn't have.

Comment: @ikegami  - _That outputs # where there weren't any before._ Yeah, but it doesn't harm anything. I wanted to keep it as a simple one liner. I could test NR and use printf accordingly. When I pulled up the question, he still had the awk in there. _He has since removed awk from the subject and added the Perl tag._ I pulled it up a while ago, but didn't get around to answering it until just now.

Comment: huh? How is inserting unwanted `#` not harmful? Sure, the assembler doesn't care, but code isn't just written for assemblers.

Answer (score 0):

```
index($0, "#") {
    $0 = sprintf("%-24s%s",
                 substr($0, 1, index($0, "#") - 1),
                 substr($0, index($0, "#")));
}
1
```